# ActiveModel Serializers: How do I serialize a resource collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, active-model-serializers

I have a `bookmarks` resource and have mapped it to serve `json` by default under my `api` namespace like so in my `routes.rb`:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    resources :bookmarks
    get ':username', to: 'users#index'
    get ':username/bookmarks/:id', to: 'users#show'
  end
```

I have a `Api::UsersController` controller and a supporting `BookmarkSerializer` that works just fine on an individual bookmark resource like `http://localhost:3000/api/emma_carter/bookmarks/87`

But when I try to hit `http://localhost:3000/api/emma_carter` which is supposed to serve all bookmarks owned by the user, I get all different kinds of errors. Here is my `Api::UsersController`

```
module Api
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
        respond_to :json

        def index
            user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
            bookmarks = user.bookmarks
            render json: bookmarks
        end

        def show
            user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
            bookmark = user.bookmarks.find_by(params[:id])
            render json: bookmark
        end
    end
end
```

The `show` method works but the index method gives me `ArgumentError in Api::UsersController#index`

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

UPDATE: Full stack trace here: https://gist.github.com/amite/b79fc42bfd73de5a07bd

**screenshot**

[image]

Here is the serializer:

```
class BookmarkSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :url, :title, :domain, :notes, :image, :created, :username
    belongs_to :user

    def created
        object.created_at
    end

    def username
        user.username
    end
end
```

Looking at other solutions on stack overflow, I have also tried other versions of my `index` method:

```
        def index
            user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
            bookmarks = user.bookmarks
            bookmarks.map { |bookmark| ::BookmarkSerializer.new(bookmark)}.to_json #updated line
        end
```

This gives me the error:

```
Missing template api/users/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

Next the last version of my `index` method looks like this:

```
def index
  user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  bookmarks = user.bookmarks
  ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(bookmarks, each_serializer: ::BookmarkSerializer).to_json
end
```

This gives me the error `uninitialized constant ActiveModel::ArraySerializer`

What am I doing wrong? I am using `rails 4.1.5` and the github version of the `active_model_serializers`
gem.

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers'
```

UPDATE: Since I am trying to output a collection of `bookmarks` I also tried using a separate serializer 
`BookmarksSerializer` but I am getting the same error: `ArgumentError in Api::UsersController#index
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

UPDATE2: Here is a version of the `index` method that kinda works in the sense that it renders the resource collection in `json` format:

```
    def index
        user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
        bookmarks = user.bookmarks

        respond_with bookmarks.to_json
    end
```

But this still does not use the `BookmarksSerializer`

```
class BookmarksSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :title
end
```

It just outputs the default hash

Full Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem 'bourbon'
gem 'neat'
gem 'bitters'
gem 'refills'

gem 'wisper'
gem 'rails-ioc'
gem 'reform'
gem 'cells'
gem "pundit"

gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers'

gem "font-awesome-rails"

gem 'simple_form'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'debugger' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'pry-rails'

  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'rspec-cells'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rb-fsevent' if `uname` =~ /Darwin/
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: check `rake routes` that will at least give you an idea on whats wrong with routes.

Comment: checked. I have `api GET  /api/:username(.:format) api/users#index {:format=>"json"}` hitting the `index` method correctly. Also the bookmarks array is getting populated correctly. I used the debugger to check that. It's just something to do with rendering the damn json

Comment: updated question with link to full stack trace: `https://gist.github.com/amite/b79fc42bfd73de5a07bd` @BilalBudhani

Comment: Can you post your gemfile here?

Comment: Updated with gemfile @anshul - thanks for taking a look man

Answer (score 6, accepted):

turns out I need to include v0.9 of the gem

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers', branch: '0-9-stable'
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try change:

```
def index
  user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  bookmarks = user.bookmarks
  bookmarks.map { |bookmark| ::BookmarkSerializer.new(bookmark)}.to_json #updated line
end
```

to:

```
def index
  user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  bookmarks = user.bookmarks
  render json: bookmarks.map { |bookmark| ::BookmarkSerializer.new(bookmark)}
end
```

Comment: tried that - it returns the default json hash map - the serializer simply does not have any affect

Comment: even with `}.to_json` in the end

Comment: yup I tried with that too - wasted entirety of last night with this - see simplified version of the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578786/index-method-in-controller-not-working-for-active-model-serializer

Comment: just for check, could you try leave just few attributes in `BookmarkSerializer` (id, title) and then `render json: bookmarks`?