# index method in controller not working for active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, active-model-serializers

I want to send a `json` response containing a collection of my `bookmarks` resource. For some reason active model serializer is just not manipulating my json as expected. It's only rendering the default response.

Here is my `BookmarksSerializer` serializer in `app/serializers/bookmarks_serializer.rb`

```
class BookmarksSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :url, :title
end
```

and my controller method inside my `Api::UsersController`which has a `respond_to :json` filter on top

```
def index
  user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  @bookmarks = user.bookmarks
  render json: @bookmarks.to_json
end
```

Instead of getting only :id, :title and :url, I am getting the full default hash

What am I doing wrong? I am using `rails 4.1.5` and the github version of the `active_model_serializers`
gem.

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers'
```

FYI: I have a show method inside the same controller and it's serializer picks up the single resource just fine. It's just the collection in the index method that is not rendering. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the master branch of active model serializers.  [The array serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/lib/active_model/serializer/array_serializer.rb) was added 4 days ago and is not accepting any arguments which is probably erroneous.  Your code should work well against `0-9-stable`.  Try:

`gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers', branch: '0-9-stable'`

Comment: I have similar problem and I change my serializer gem to the latest stable version but it seems not to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

render :json => @bookmarks, each_serializer: BookmarksSerializer

Comment: does not work: I get ArgumentError in Api::UsersController#index
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0). Here is a full stack trace: https://gist.github.com/amite/b79fc42bfd73de5a07bd